# Is there a benefit in encrypting SQLLite DB in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption, core-data

If iOS already has passcode ( https://www.hexnode.com/blogs/iphone-encryption-everything-you-need-to-know/ ) we understand that storage is encrypted by default using AES

In that case, is there any benefit in encrypting the SQL lite DB on top of default iOS encryption?

We are now doing sqllite encryption/decryption which seems to be costly in iOS and would like to get trid of this activity.

Comment: Anyone who can gain access to database files has the device passcode so is effectively the device "owner". Do you want to protect the data from the device owner? Ie is it some proprietary data that the app makes use of or is it just the user's data. If the latter, then there is little point in adding additional encryption. If it is your app's data (say, some commercially valuable database) then it might be worth it, but you need to consider how you are protecting against a key recovery attack